# Insert or Update data into tables in SQlite

Tags: sqlite, cordova, web-sql, unique-index

Am working in HTML5 + PhoneGap Applications with **SQlite**

For updating the table in SQlite ; am using **REPLACE INTO** method.

Here is example code ; [: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ccc33/2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ccc33/2)

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
id integer primary key autoincrement,
name VARCHAR(10),
date DATE,
job VARCHAR(16),
hours VARCHAR(16)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myindex ON mytable(NAME);
```

Here **NAME** is the UNIQUE INDEX vale.

**Query**

```
REPLACE INTO mytable (NAME, DATE, JOB, HOURS)

VALUES ('BOB', '12/01/01', 'PM','20');

REPLACE INTO mytable (NAME, DATE, JOB, HOURS)

VALUES ('BOB', '12/01/01', 'PM','32');

REPLACE INTO mytable (NAME, DATE, JOB, HOURS)

VALUES ('BOB', '14/01/01', 'PM','35');

REPLACE INTO mytable (NAME, DATE, JOB, HOURS)

VALUES ('BOBg', '12/01/01', 'PM','350');

SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

But when Run the Query ; i seen that the primary key **id** is incremented [image] . But my need its only update when **NAME** is same.

Is there any solution for this? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In your query when there is a unique constraint on (NAME, DATE, JOB, HOURS) or their combination, and it is violated, the records gets deleted and inserted with the new values. So the key id is incremented

If you want to something like and UPSERT do it like:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO mytable (id, NAME, Date, JOB, HOURS)
 SELECT old.id, new.NAME, new.Date, new.JOB, new.HOURS
 FROM ( SELECT
     'BOB' AS name,
     '12/01/01' AS NAME,
     'PM'  AS JOB,
     '32'  AS JOB
 ) AS new
 LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT id, NAME, Date, JOB, HOURS
     FROM mytable
 ) AS old ON new.NAME= old.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont write autoincrement while creating id column.

http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html